# How to replace everything between PORT= and )

Tags: replace, multiple-lines

I have a (copy of) oracle listener log, and would like to replace the portnumber in every line.
These are always of the form
`(PORT=1234)`  with sometimes 4 and sometimes 5 numbers.

So an exampleline, and I've anonimized it completely, but there are thousands of lines:

```
07-SEP-2020 06:34:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYDB01)(CID=(PROGRAM=prog1@serv99)(HOST=client1283)(USER=john))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=16.30.34.11)(PORT=12770)) * establish * MYDB01 * 0
```

I'd like to have that:

```
07-SEP-2020 06:34:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MYDB01)(CID=(PROGRAM=prog1@serv99)(HOST=client1283)(USER=john))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=16.30.34.11)(PORT=xxxxx)) * establish * MYDB01 * 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `:s` command with a pattern that matches the port number and a replacement of `xxxxx` (or whatever you prefer.) Use a range of `%` to match the whole file.

When matching the pattern itself, a very useful feature of Vim regexes is [`\zs`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs) and [`\ze`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cze) to mark the start and end of the match. That helps you match the characters that come before it (`PORT=`) or after (`)`) the digits, but only replace the digits themselves. (Without having to deal with regex look-ahead and look-behind zero-match syntax, or use match groups.)

So, in your particular case, you can use:

```
:%s/PORT=\zs\d\+\ze)/xxxxx/g
```

The `\d\+` part matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to create a macro. That is a small recording of keystrokes that can be repeated a number of times. You would need to record keystrokes of the following steps. Macros are a powerful Vim feature worth learning.

0. Start recording the macro by pressing `qa`. `a` would be the name of the macro.
1. Search for the pattern `PORT` by using `/`. Press `<Enter>` to find the first occurrence.
2. Press the lowercase `e` two times to move the cursor to the end of the `=` sign.
3. Press `w` to move the cursor to the first number.
4. Press `ct)` that means change until `)` which will put you in insert mode. That will work on 4 or 5 or any character until it gets to the `)`.
5. Type the `x` character five times and press `<ESC>`.
6. Search for the next occurrence of `PORT` with `n`.
7. Stop the recording by pressing `q`.
8. Press `10@a` to run the macro 10 times.

Comment: Added some formatting. I prefer `f=` to `ee` as it’s less likely to break. But great answer, and welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Nice. I like the `f=` because it brings you just to where you need to go.